# Ant error when I try to run my program

Tags: java, ant, rmi

I have a problem in Ant that keeps bugging me and I do not seem to come to a solution. I have an RMI project in java, which is finished, and the and file below:

```
<project name="StockageRMI" default="compile">

    <target name="compile">
        <javac destdir="classes">
            <src path="src/db/"/>
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib/">  
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />  
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="classes/">  
                    <include name="**/*.class" />  
                </fileset>    
            </classpath>
        </javac>

        <javac destdir="classes">
            <src path="src/stockage"/>
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib/">  
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />  
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="classes/">  
                    <include name="**/*.class" />  
                </fileset>    
            </classpath>
        </javac>

        <javac destdir="classes">
            <src path="src/server"/>
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib/">  
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />  
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="classes/">  
                    <include name="**/*.class" />  
                </fileset>    
            </classpath>
        </javac>

        <javac destdir="classes">
            <src path="src/client"/>
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib/">  
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />  
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="classes/">  
                    <include name="**/*.class" />  
                </fileset>    
            </classpath>
        </javac>

    </target>

    <target name="rmic" depends="compile">
        <rmic classname="stockage.StockageImpl" base="classes/">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib/">  
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />  
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="classes/">  
                    <include name="**/*.class" />  
                </fileset>    
            </classpath>
        </rmic>
    </target>

    <target name="runServer" depends="rmic,runStockage">
       <java classname="server.ServerImpl" fork="true" failonerror="true" >
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib/">  
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />  
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="classes/">  
                    <include name="**/*.class" />  
                </fileset>    
            </classpath>
       </java>
    </target>

    <target name="runStockage">
       <java classname="stockage.StockageImpl" fork="true" failonerror="true" >
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib/">  
                    <include name="**/*.jar" />  
                </fileset>
                <fileset dir="classes/">  
                    <include name="**/*.class" />  
                </fileset>    
            </classpath>
       </java>
    </target>


</project>
```

The target "compile" and "rmic" work just fine, the problem is when I try to run "runStockage".I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: stockage/StockageImpl
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: stockage.StockageImpl
     [java]  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
     [java]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
     [java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
     [java]  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
     [java]  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

This is very strange, because if I try to do this in terminal, the java command works fine, and it has the same classpath as the javac, because it has the same dependencies:

```
javac -cp lib/mongo-java-driver-2.11.1.jar:lib/rmiio-2-1.0.0.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:classes -d classes src/stockage/StockageImpl.java

rmic -classpath lib/mongo-java-driver-2.11.1.jar:lib/rmiio-2-1.0.0.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:classes -d classes stockage.StockageImpl

java -classpath lib/mongo-java-driver-2.11.1.jar:lib/rmiio-2-1.0.0.jar:lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:classes server.ServerImpl
```

All the three above commands work just fine, the problem is in ant. As you can see, javac, java and rmic use the same dependencies and jar files, so I did the same thing in Ant but it does not work. I am sure that it is something stupid at the middle of this, but I cannot seem to figure it out for the past 6 hours. Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem may be with your source path; try looking in your `classes` folder and see if you have a `stockage` folder containing a `StockageImpl.class` file.

I think you may want to change the source paths for your compile target to `src` instead of `src/stockage` (which would also allow you to have a single `<compile>` task instead of two), or if you for any reason still want to have them separated, e.g. you just need to compile files in `stockage` and `db` and not others, you should change the `destdir` to `classes/stockage` and `classes/db`, respectively.